# Can someone help me decipher this function?

Tags: php

I am trying to match numbers within an array with a range of numbers, i have been told to use preg_match. Unfortunately I am not good at regular expressions. Any suggestions?

```
<?php

$range = range(89000000,89499999);
foreach($range as $number)
{

     if (preg_match("/89304043/", $number))
     {
      die( "Valid carrier Number" );
     }
     else
     {
       die( "Invalid carrier Number" );
     }


}
?>
```

Comment: `$range = range(89000000,89499999)` -- ouch.

Comment: This is one of the more painful pieces of code I've seen in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$number=(int)$number;
$valid=($number>=89000000 && $number<=89499999);
```

`$valid` is now either true or false. I typecast the number to ensure it's an integer (And I presumed that there were no non-numeric characters in it.

Comment: Thank you very much this options was actually the best way of doing it !

Answer (score 0):

Try with ,

```
gmp_cmp("89304043", $number);
```

This is for long numbers. If this is also out of range,
Try this library, http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Answer (score 0):

```
function myrange() {  
  if($number > 89000000 && $number < 89499999) {  
    echo 'Number is between range';
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your foreach will execute only once, and it'll die at 89000000... Die invalid should be after the foreach loop.

```
<?php

$range = range(89000000,89499999);
foreach($range as $number)
{
    if (preg_match("/89304043/", $number))
    {
        die( "Valid carrier Number" );
    }
}
// If we're here - the number is invalid, as we've not "died" yet
die( "Invalid carrier Number" );

?>
```

Although the approach is weird for the problem at hand... But hey, may be the real problem is something else...